# Is it possible to inject code into a Java object transmitted over a network through Man In The Middle attack?

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, network-programming, deserialization

In Java, one could do the following to send and receive objects over the network (Without encryption).

```
class Dog {
    public void bark(){ System.out.println("Woof! Woof!"); }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
Dog fido = new Dog();
Socket socket = new Socket(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2"), 1234);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(fido);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

**Server.java**

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket client = server.accept();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
Dog fido = (Dog)ois.readObject();
ois.close();

fido.bark();
```

My question is, suppose you have successfully established an interception point between two network devices which are sending Java objects back and forth on an unsecured link and that you know their protocol and can modify their data, is it possible to inject Java byte code into the objects to change their behavior?

In our little example, is it possible to make `fido` **"moo!"** instead of barking?

Comment: You're sending *data*, not Java *code*, so no.

Comment: Note that object serialization only records values and what class the values should be inserted in to.  No byte code.  That must be present already to both client and server.  So you can modify the class to be deserialized (to something else) and it's data.

Comment: Note however that researches have found ways to create object graphs that when deserialized lead to remote code execution: https://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you serialize an object in Java, only the fields of this object are serialized. The bytecodes on client and server have to be equal (or at least compatible). This is enforced by the [serialVersionUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization.

Considering this, you could change the behaviour, if you change the value of a field. Given this implementation of `Dog`, you could intercept the request and change the value of sound to `"Moo!"`.

```
public class Dog {
    private String sound = "Woof! Woof!";
    public void bark(){ System.out.println(sound); }
}
```

But since `"Woof! Woof!"` in your original implementation is a compile-time constant, it will not be serialized, because it is not possible to change it during runtime.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand how Java serializes Objects to and from streams.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes if your data stream in any form is untrusted/compromised then a vulnerability in the serialization framework that you're using can result in Java code getting executed that could, in turn, launch something more malicious.

Apache Common Collection had few  such vulnerabilities.  Very briefly the class was instantiated based on the names in the data stream instead of expected name. [This would result in an arbitrary class getting instantiated](http://gursevkalra.blogspot.in/2016/01/ysoserial-commonscollections1-exploit.html).

Have a look at the Java [deserialization FAQ](https://www.christian-schneider.net/JavaDeserializationSecurityFAQ.html) to better understand how to reliably work with them.